# Create filtered file out of overlapping coordinates

Tags: qgis, python, pandas

I have two CSV files with multiple columns of data (csv_1 and csv_2) which I have as Panda dataframes in Python as `cal` and `pog`. They both contain an 'x' and a 'y' column.

I want to make a new dataset that contains only the rows of `cal` that share both 'x' values and 'y' values as `pog` (i.e. the datapoint shares the same unique location). Both datasets have hundreds of thousands of rows so I have found it a bit tricky to implement this in Python effectively.

Currently I have the following code:

```
cro = []

for i in range(len(cal)):
    if (cal['x'][i] not in pog['x']) or (cal['y'][i] not in pog['y']) or cal['x'][i] == 0 or cal['x'][i] == None:
        continue
    for j in range(len(pog)):
        if pog['x'][j] == cal['x'][i] and pog['y'][j] == cal['y'][i]:
            cro.append(cal.iloc[i, ])

cro_df = pd.Dataframe(cro)
cro.to_csv('19_03_precise_cropped_lcm.csv')
```

The dataframes are hundreds of thousands of rows (over 50 MB). This code seems to be taking way too long (multiple days of running). I am wondering if there is a faster method using Python or QGIS to get the same results.

Edit:

I've made a system that uses a unique ID for each coordinate combination:

```
for i in range(len(pog)):
    if (cal['coord_id'][i] == pog['coord_id'][i]):
        continue
    for j in range(len(cal)):
        if pog['x'][i] == cal['x'][j] and pog['y'][i] == cal['y'][j]:
            cro.append(cal.iloc[i, ])
            count += 1
            if count % 100 == 0:
                print("loading:", count, "progress: ", count/len(pog))
            continue
```

Still expected to take over a week to calculate everything.
The coord_id generation method I used was the following

```
id_gen = []
for i in range(len(cal)):
    id_gen.append(str(cal['x'][i]) + "_" + str(cal['y'][i]))
```

the list was then inserted into their respective dataframe at the end.

```
cal.insert(24, 'coord_id', id_gen, allow_duplicates=False)
```

Comment: X and Y equivalence is a fraught concept, and your methodology has you doing hundreds of millions of unindexed comparisons. Yeah, it's going to take a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the coordinates are exactly the same in both dataframes (same number of decimal places etc.), use [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `how="inner"`, to find the matching rows:

> Merge DataFrame or named Series objects with a database-style join.

```
import pandas as pd
from timeit import default_timer

start = default_timer()
cal = pd.read_csv(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/dsfdsf/cal.csv", delimiter=";")
print(cal.shape)
#(100001, 2)
print(cal.head())
#               x             y
# 0  741373.179284  6.227272e+06
# 1  206274.463075  6.146580e+06
# 2  316903.472729  7.595983e+06
# 3  805859.277965  6.836434e+06
# 4  748065.873105  7.494897e+06

pog = pd.read_csv(r"/home/bera/Desktop/gistest/dsfdsf/pog.csv", delimiter=";")
print(pog.shape)
#(100001, 2)
print(pog.head())
#                x             y
# 0  870985.083339  6.739584e+06
# 1  807621.872207  7.047371e+06
# 2  154134.350128  6.766908e+06
# 3  270004.989673  7.378488e+06
# 4  479520.465718  6.702817e+06

result = pd.merge(left=cal, left_on=["x", "y"], 
                  right=pog, right_on=["x", "y"], how="inner") #"Inner join" where the x and y columns in both dataframes match

print(result.shape)
#(20001, 2)
print(f"Time: {round(default_timer()-start, 1)} s.")
#Time: 0.1 s.
```

If they arent exactly the same, create geodataframes and [sjoin_nearest](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin_nearest.html) with a max_distance set